# Movement script won't go forward whenever my character turns around

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this movement script attached to my player however whenever I turn for example 90 degrees it won't go forward if I press w, now I know this is because z is different since I moved the camera however how do I fix this?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

public Rigidbody rb;
float forwardForce = 500f;
float sidewaysForce = 500f;
float jumpForce = 100f;
// Start is called before the first frame update
// Update is called once per frame
public Vector3 jump;

public bool isGrounded;
void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}
void OnCollisionStay()
{
    isGrounded = true;
}


void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (Input.GetKey("d"))
    {
        rb.AddForce(sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey("a"))
    {
        rb.AddForce(-sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey("w"))
    {
        rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey("s"))
    {
        rb.AddForce(0, 0, -forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey("space") && isGrounded)
    {

        rb.AddForce(0, jumpForce, 0);
        isGrounded = false;

    }
}
}
```

Comment: You just need to get a normalised vector that points `forwards` from your character and multiply the force by that, then feed that into the `AddForce` (you can just pass a `Vector3`) - you can use `transform.forward` to get the forward vector for most objects (it does depend on what you are getting `forward` from though)

Comment: Any way you could simplify that or give me an example code because what you're explaining might be simple but I'm pretty dumb.

Comment: Inexperienced does not = dumb my friend - I'll put an answer up.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *point in any direction* in Unity (or math in general) you need a unit or **normalised** vector - that's one where all the components add up to 1.

For example (assuming `x,y,z`) `0, 0, 1` is a unit vector and `0, 0.5, 0.5` is also a unit vector.

Multiplying this vector by a scalar value (a single numeric value) gives you a distance or magnitude.

For example, multiplying a unit vector by 50 will give a vector where the components all add up to 50, so in the above examples the vectors become `0, 0, 50` and `0, 25, 25`.

The `Vector3` class in Unity has an overload that allows you to multiply the components:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-operator_multiply.html

With that in mind, any unit vector can be scaled simply by multiplying it using the `*` operator.

```
var myUnitVector = new Vector3(0, 0.5, 0.5);

var myScaledVector = myUnitVector * 10; // myScaledVector is now (0, 5, 5)
```

`AddForce` accepts a `Vector3` as a parameter (you are currently supplying each component individually), so in order to get your move force, you just need to multiply your `forward` vector by the magnitude of the force.

Unity has a `forward` property on all objects that exist in a scene via the `Transform` component. The `Transform` component represents the objects position and rotation in the scene.

So, for your case, depending on if you want to use the camera rotation or the actual character rotation the code is similar. I'll assume you want to use the characters rotation for now:

```
// Keep hold of the transform component for this gameobject
Transform transform;
forwardForce = 500f;

void Start()
{
    // Get the transform object on startup
    transform = GetComponent<Transform>();
}

void FixedUpdate() 
{
    // Press forward or whatever the condition may be
    if (someCondition) 
    {
        rb.AddForce(transform.forward * forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

This will apply force forwards in relation to the direction the game object is facing.

If you want the camera facing instead (if your game object is not rotating with the camera) then you will need to find the camera gameobject and then cache the transform from the camera instead of the current gameobject.

Note that `Transform` also has other helper properties: `transform.up` and `transform.right`. You can get left/down by just inverting those vectors e.g. `-transform.right` or `-transform.up` respectively.

You can use those properties to do your sideways movement for your WASD.

Comment: If it wouldn't be a pain do you know how to do this sideways too?

Comment: @RandomPerson I mentioned that in the post - it's the last 2 paragraphs.

Answer (score 1):

[`AddForce`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) uses the world space. So no matter how your object is rotated it will always apply your forces along the Unity global X,Y,Z axes.

You want to use [`AddForceRelative`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddRelativeForce.html) which interprets the given values in the local space of that object (so using its own X,Y,Z axes)

> Adds a force to the rigidbody relative to its coordinate system.

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (Input.GetKey("d"))
    {
        rb.AddForceRelative(sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey("a"))
    {
        rb.AddForceRelative(-sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey("w"))
    {
        rb.AddForceRelative(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey("s"))
    {
        rb.AddForceRelative(0, 0, -forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey("space") && isGrounded)
    {
        // Here you most probably would want to keep the global UP direction ;)
        rb.AddForce(0, jumpForce, 0);
        isGrounded = false;
    }
}
```

In general you might want to use a different object for the movement than the camera.

> Why?

Because otherwise

- if your camera looks downward and you press W -> you add a force downward so kind of trying to press the player into the ground
- if your camera looks upward and you press W -> you add a force upward so depending on the strength of your forces this might enable players to fly around ^^

So I would rather use a hierarchy like

```
Player (This one receives the movement WASD + ONLY global Y-axis rotation)
|--Camera (This one receives ONLY local X-axis rotation)
```

Of course you can handle that both within one single script but that's where you should apply the given input.
This way the `Player` will actually never look downward or upward because it is only ever rotated around the global Y axis (looking left and right).

The camera is the only thing looking downward and upward but we don't use its local space for the movement but the one of the `Player` so the Camera orientation doesn't matter for the movement.